# проблема с history api

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

здравствуйте, использую функцию history.pushtate для асинхронного изменения  того что идет после домена.

но есть проблема, некоторые браузеры которые не поддерживают history не просто не позволяют использовать эту функцию, а код js полностью не работает и сайт становится не пригодным. как можно решить эту ситуацию? сделать ли какую то проверку перед запуском функции, которая будет определять поддерживает ли браузер её или нет, предотвращая запуск

Answer (score 2):

Проверить это довольно просто:

```
function isHistoryApi() {
  return !!(window.history && history.pushState);
}
```

Другой вопрос, что раз Вы используете history, то, возможно и многие другие возможности html5. Если оно так, то это может быть причиной, почему ничего не работает в определенных браузерах.

Для решения подобной проблемы был создан [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/docs/). По приведенной ссылке можно найти список фич, которые можно проверить при помощи Modernizr'a.

Answer (score 0):

Проверяйте в лоб существование функции

```
if(window.history && history.pushState) {
    // .. Здесь ваш код
}
```

Либо отлавливайте ошибки

```
try {
    // .. Ваш код с history.pushState
} catch(e) {}
```